# Application end point not reachable when Spring boot is upgraded to 2.7.12 on Azure

Tags: spring, spring-boot, azure-application-insights, spring-boot-actuator, azure-appservice

Spring boot application on Azure app service is giving 404 error after upgrading from 2.7.5 version to 2.7.12.
But the same application is working fine in local.
Application is up and running and I do not see any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Spring boot application on Azure app service is giving 404 error.

1. The issue could be due to a configuration issue, check the logs to know what causing the error.
2. Check if the application is configured correctly for the new version of Spring Boot which is compatible with the configuration settings.
3. Make sure all the required files are deployed properly.

If you are deploying your spring boot application within docker image to Azure App Service ,I found a [similar](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33974) issue which may help to fix your issue.

---

*Alternatively, you can try deploying your application through CLI or VS code.*

I have created a simple ***spring-boot*** application with ***version 2.7.0***. and deployed to ***Azure App Service*** through command line:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Response:**

[image]
[image]

***Upgraded spring version to 2.7.12 and tried to deploy the application:***

[image]

**Response:**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Then link provided above solved the issue.  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33974. We have to upgrade javainsight agent or set config property ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~3". It is working fine now.